# Get the id of a clicked Html link and use it as parameter for an SqlDataSource in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, hyperlink, sqldatasource

I have a large Database and a lot of 'let's say' names and I have a definitions for these names in another table, so I add an html link between all the names like this:

```
<a href="Test.aspx" target="_blank" id="2384">John</a>
<a href="Test.aspx" target="_blank" id="2334">Smith</a>
```

and a lot of these names, when a link is clicked a new tab will open so, in the Test.aspx I have GridVew bounded with an SqlDataSource, what I want is to take id from the link that been clicked a pass it to the SqlDataSource parameter like this:

```
SqlDataSourceTest.SelectParameters["IdFromAnchor"].DefaultValue = theClickedLinkID
```

So how could I pass the ID to the Parameter o what should I use, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best off just putting the IDs as a query string parameter and then reading in that parameter on the next page. Make sure you sanitize it though, as you could be open to SQL injections:

```
<a href="Test.aspx?id=2384" target="_blank" id="2384">John</a>
<a href="Test.aspx?id=2334" target="_blank" id="2334">Smith</a>
```

Then just do:

```
Request.QueryString["id"];
```

**Beware though, that can be easily changed by users to any id they please, so if you don't want users to see things with id's other than what they can see, you'd have to perform additional checks there.**

Comment: +1 For the mention of SQL injection, however, using this method, couldn't someone presumably retrieve information about anyone in the database just by modifying the id in the querystring? Depending on the context, this could be a very bad idea

Comment: @DGibbs Yeah definitely a good shout, I've included that disclaimer in my answer. Hopefully the context isn't as open as we think :P

Comment: If there's stuff only certain users are allowed to see, you should always check if what they're accessing is within what they should be able to see, irregardless of how you solve the id stuff :)

Comment: @Svish Yeah definitely, but I thought it was worth pointing that out to the OP just be to clear :)

Comment: I tried that but it gave me an error "the resource cannot be found". I guess that happened because it can't find the targeted page !

Comment: @user2090189 Hmmm, What exactly threw that error? You may need to prefix that URL with your application URL.

Comment: @mattytommo yeah I figure out the problem everything went well, but the gridview does not view anything !

Comment: Can you debug and see that the query string value is there? If so, somethings wrong further on in the process.

Comment: I debug it, there were a database error ! everything works well know ! Thanks for this great idea.

Comment: @user2090189 Sweet! No problems, glad I could help :)